# Angular 13 does not work with @nestjs/ng-universal but works correctly with @nguniversal/express-engine

Tags: express, nestjs, angular-universal, angular13

I recently installed angular 13 and tried to install @nestjs/ng-universal with

**ng add @nestjs/ng-universal**

which worked for previous angular versions but I get **Package successfully installed** then this error:

```
*An unhandled exception occurred: Package subpath './schematics/utils' is not defined by 
"exports" in C:\Users\ADMIN\kiambol\node_modules@nguniversal\express-engine\package.json
See "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-1gySjP\angular-errors.log" for further 
details.*
```

**And the full error in the angular-errors.log file is:**

```
[error] Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './schematics/utils' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\ADMIN\kiambol\node_modules@nguniversal\express-engine\package.json
at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:299:9)
at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:522:3)
at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:449:36)
at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:489:31)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:27)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\ADMIN\kiambol\node_modules@nestjs\ng-universal\schematics\install\index.js:15:17)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
```

When I look at the angular project files, nothing has changed and the server files is not setup setup. I tried to create different angular projects just to see if my angular project was not select correctly then added **ng add @nestjs/ng-universal**  again and still got the same result.

To test things out I tried installing **@nguniversal/express-engine** with the **ng add** command and this installed correctly with no issues and everything was setup correctly.

**Did anything change in the installation process; am I doing something wrong; or is Angular 13 not yet supported?**

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK i think it an error from the `@nestjs/ng-universal` side.

as a quick & dirty solution start by installing `@nguniversal/express-engine`
then go to `node_modules/@nguniversal/express-engine/package.json` and :

- **remove** : `"type": "module"`

- **add**  in `exports`:

```json
    "./schematics/utils": {
      "types": "./schematics/utils/index.d.ts",
      "esm2020": "./schematics/utils/index.js",
      "es2020": "./schematics/utils/index.js",
      "es2015": "./schematics/utils/index.js",
      "node": "./schematics/utils/index.js",
      "default": "./schematics/utils/index.js"
    }
```

then `ng add @nestjs/ng-universal` should work fine and by updating the packages it should revert the changes

Answer (score 2):

With Angular 13, "ng add @nestjs/ng-universal" creates error. Because it uses the latest verison of library, that is 6th version. Intstead you can use "ng add @nestjs/ng-universal@5" and it works perfectly fine.